# Ruby on Rails - Can I choose where a specific notice will be shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alert, notice

In my application I am using *Bootstrap flash* in my header to show all notices/alerts.

Here is my code:

```
.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
  = bootstrap_flash
.clearfix
.row
  = yield
```

I have a vote controller that I would like to show its alert in completely different place, next to the vote button itself.

How can I *"choose"* where a specific notice from specific controller will be shown?

Comment: You need to create a separate layout for vote controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a HAML way. Just copying the @David answer with haml.

If you change your layout to:

```
.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
  = bootstrap_flash unless content_for?(:custom_flash)
```

And in the view for your form you put:

```
- content_for(:custom_flash) do
  = bootstrap_flash
```

And by the button you do:

```
= yield(:custom_flash)
```

This way your normal flashes will be shown unless you define a content_for(:custom_flash)

Answer (score 0):

(I do not know this fancy HAML-thingy ;) )

If you change your layout to:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <% unless content_for?(:custom_flash) do %>
    <%= bootstrap_flash %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And in the view for your form you put:

```
<% content_for(:custom_flash) do %>
  <%= bootstrap_flash %>
<% end %>
```

And by the button you do:

```
<%= yield(:custom_flash) %>
```

This way your normal flashes will be shown unless you define a `content_for(:custom_flash)`.

I hope you can solve the `.erb`, or perhaps someone can help me to do it in HAML ;)

Comment: Thanks David. Don't need to define the "custom_flash" in my vote controller?

Comment: Just use the normal flash[:error] or whatever you use to print flashes right now.